# React-redux action is not getting dispatched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-thunk

I am trying to implement authentication with google in my react next js app. I am sending the access token to my backend and the backend checks if the token is valid and if it is good it returns a token in the header to access the protected resources. when I integrate redux, redux-thunk seems to block the request, the request is only sent to google and not to my backend. I do not receive any response from my backend and I even observed the logs in the server but no request.

this code works well and it returns the token

```
export const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    const access_token = response.accessToken;
    const tokenSend = {access_token}
        return  axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/api/auth/google/login`, tokenSend)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
            })
            .catch(error=> console.log(error))
};
```

but with this code  below with redux-thunk not working, the request is sent to google as well but not in my backend

```
export const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    const access_token = response.accessToken;
    const tokenSend = {access_token}
    return (dispatch) => {
       return  axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/api/auth/google/login`, tokenSend)
            .then(response => {
                  console.log(response.data)

            })
            .catch(error=> console.log(error))
    }
};
```

The login button

```
 <GoogleLogin
     clientId={config.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
     buttonText="Login"
     onSuccess={responseGoogle}
     onFailure={onFailure}
     isSignedIn 
 />
```

Comment: I don't know what `GoogleLogin` but assuming you have a functional component you could try `const dispatch = useDispatch()` and the handler: `onSuccess={response=>dispatch(responseGoogle(response))}`

Comment: thank you, it's working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is now working, thanks to [hmr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1641941/hmr) for giving me the answer.
i just had to trigger the response manually by doing

```
 <GoogleLogin
     clientId={config.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
     buttonText="Login"
     onSuccess={response => dispatch(responseGoogle)}
     onFailure={onFailure}
     isSignedIn 
 />
```